# PhantomJS loads much less HTML than other drivers

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to load one web page and get some elements from it. So the first thing I do is to check the page using "inspect element". When I search for the tags I'm looking for, I can see them (in Chrome).

But when I try to do `driver.get(url)` and then `driver.find_element_by_...`, it doesn't find those elements because they aren't in the source code.

I think that it is probably because it doesn't load the whole page but only a part.

Here is an example:

I'm trying to find ads on the web page.

```
PREPARED_TABOOLA_BLOCK = """//div[contains(@id,'taboola') and not(ancestor::div[contains(@id,'taboola')])]"""

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=["--load-images=false"])
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()

def find_taboola_blocks_selenium(url):
    driver.get(url)
    taboola_blocks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(PREPARED_TABOOLA_BLOCK)
    return taboola_blocks


print len(find_taboola_blocks_selenium('http://www.breastfeeding-problems.com/breastfeeding-a-sick-baby.html'))
driver.get('http://www.breastfeeding-problems.com/breastfeeding-a-sick-baby.html')
print len(driver.page_source)
```

**OUTPUTS:**

Using PhantomJS:

> 0
>
> 85103

Using ChromeDriver:

> 3
>
> 420869

Do you know how to make PhantomJS to load as much Html as possible or any other way to solve this?

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, have you tried adding a delay with `time.sleep()` after calling `driver.get()`?

Comment: @alecxe Hi alecxe, yes I have. 20 secs. No change at all. But I noticed that maximized Chrome is cca 1900x1600 or something similar and PhantomJS is 1366x768.

Comment: Okay, have you tried to scroll down to the bottom of the page one or more times? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Yes I've tried this too. To be sure, I tried 6 lines: driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
And checked in Chrome driver if it works.

Comment: Okay, great, does `driver.maximize_window()` call make any difference?

Comment: Also, it could be the XPath locator causing issues. Have you tried to compare counts for, say, `//div[contains(@id,'taboola')]` locator?

Comment: I'm going to check it but I'm afraid that comparing lengths of page_sources points to different amount of loaded HTML but I'm newbie so it's only my though.

Comment: Ok, so results: print len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//div[contains(@id,'taboola')]""")) For PhantomJS: 0 for Chrome: 3

Comment: Have you tried to take a screenshot to see whether it is the same page (mobile version or broken page)?

Comment: Btw, what are those "taboola" blocks? PhantomJS is a little bit known for not loading all advertisement scripts.

Comment: Taboola is some type of ads like google ads I think. Ok, I get it but it works for most pages so the problem has to be somewhere else in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Can you compare the request that ChromeDriver is making versus the request you are making in PhantomJS? Since you are only doing GET for the specified url, you may not be including other request parameters that are needed to get the advertisements.

The open() method may give you a better representation of what you are looking for here: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because PhantomJS, by default, renders in a really small window, which makes it load the mobile version of the site.  And with the PhantomJSDriver, calling maximizeWindow() (or maximize_window() in python) does absolutely nothing, since there is no rendered window to maximize.  You will have to explicitly set the window's render size with:

edit:  Below is the Java solution.  I'm not entirely sure what the Python solution would be when setting the window size, but it should be similar.

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1200));
```

edit again:  Found the python version:

```
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1200)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've tried this before and it does not works. driver.set_window_size(1938,1050) <- I had this line right after initializing a driver. Or should I put it after get?

Comment: Oh, and I've forgot that even if I did that, the maximum size was something about 1300 x 700

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS 1.x is a really old browser. It only uses SSLv3 (now disabled on most sites) by default and doesn't implement most cutting edge functionality.

Advertisement scripts are usually delivered over HTTPS (SSLv3/TLS) and usually use some obscure feature of JavaScript which is not well tested or simply not implemented in PhantomJS.

If you use PhantomJS < v1.9.8 then you should use those commandline options (`service_args`): `--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any`.

If iframes or strange cross-domain requests are necessary for the page/ads to work, then add `--web-security=false` to the `service_args`.

If this still doesn't solve the problem, then try upgrading to PhantomJS 2.0.0. You might need to compile it yourself on Linux.

Comment: Thank you but I've tried to upgrade to 2.0.0 PhantomJS and use those options and it still does not work (the same thing but with chromedriver works, but it has to be headless)

Comment: In that case, you can use xvfb to run Chrome headlessly.